# Can a complex non-skew Hermitian matrix have purely imaginary eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

I am trying to determine if a certain matrix can have purely imaginary eigenvalues.  My question in its most general form is weather a complex matrix that is not skew-Hermitian and irreducible  can contain eigenvalues on the imaginary axis.

My question, however, arises from a more particular instance.  I am trying to determine if there can be eigenvalues on the imaginary axis of the matrix $(j\omega I + L)_{(kl)}$.

Here, $\omega$ is some real number, $A_{(kl)}$ denotes the sub-matrix of $A$ obtained by deleting the $k$-th row and $l$th column, and $L$ is the combinatorial Laplacian of a connected graph.

The Matrix-Tree theorem tells us that the determinant of any sub-matrix of $L$ is equal to the number of spanning trees in the graph.  This, of course, implies that $L_{(k,l)}$ is invertible.  I would like to know $(j\omega I + L)_{(kl)}$ inherits that property, i.e. it is invertible for any choice of $\omega \in R$.

If for example, $L_{(kl)}$ does contain a purely imaginary eigenvalue, then there exists an $\omega$ that makes the matrix singular.

Comment: The matrix $\left(\begin{matrix i & i \\ 0 & i\end{matrix}\right)$ hs $i$ as only eigenvalue, is not skew Hermitian (not even diagonalizable). So...?

Comment: Yes, that provides a simple example.  I've modified my question to further require that the matrix is irreducible, which I neglected to mention originally.  

Comment: If you multiply by $i$, then the question is: is a complex matrix having only real eigenvalues necessarily Hermitian. The answer is "no". For example $\left(\begin{array} {cc} 5&3\\2&4 \end{array}\right)$.

Comment: To prove the theorem you want (if it's true), I suspect you would have to use the fact that $L$ has all positive entries.

Comment: Is the $j$ in $j\omega I$ the imaginary unit or the column index as in $L_{(i,j)}$?

Comment: $L$ does not have positive entries, but it is a symmetric M-matrix (positive on the diagonal, non-positive on the off diagonals).

Comment: I did a little numerical experimentation, and suspect that the theorem you want isn't true, but I am not going to find a counterexample without some serious thought. 

Comment: Federico, sorry, that is confusing.  The $j$ is the imaginary unit; I edited the original post.

Peter, for the specialized problem when dealing with the graph Laplacian, I have been unable to find a counter-example through extensive simulations.

When $k=l$, i.e. looking at principal submatrices, the claim holds, since the eigenvalues of $(j\omega I + L)_{k,k}$ are the eigenvalues of $L_{k,k}$ (which does not contain the origin) shifted by $j\omega$. 

Answer (score 3):

Take $$ L = \left( \begin{array} {rrrr} 7&-2&-2&-3\\\\ -2 & 4 & 0 & -2 \\\\  -2 & 0 &4 &
 -2 \\\\ -3 & -2 & -2 & 7 \end{array} \right).$$ Remove the last row and first column. The remaining matrix has two purely imaginary eigenvalues. Does this answer your question?

UPDATE:

Can I point out that, even though this matrix has imaginary eigenvalues, there is no value of $\omega$ such that $(j\omega I + L)_{(k,\ell)}$ has determinant zero, where $j = \sqrt{-1}$. This is because the operations of adding the identity and removing row $k$ and column $\ell$ do not commute. You may want to rethink your question.

Comment: This is a counter example to the general question, thank-you.  However, for the question related to the Laplacian, I am only considering unweighted graphs.

Comment: In fact, it's a counterexample to the Laplacian question for weighted graphs, which makes me suspect that there is probably a counterexample for unweighted graphs.

Comment: That would be very interesting.  May I ask how you constructed the example for weighted graphs?  As I mentioned, I have yet to find an example for unweighted graphs.

Comment: @dan: I stuck a lot of parameters in (with the symmetry you see) and did a small-scale computer search. I don't know how well that would work for unweighted graphs, especially if you've been testing them. 